# import pygame._view fails

Tags: python, pygame

When I run

```
python -c "import pygame._view"
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _view
```

I have python 2.7.13 and pygame 1.9.3 --- when I run

```
pip show pygame
```

I get the following

```
Name: pygame
Version: 1.9.3
Summary: Python Game Development
Home-page: http://www.pygame.org
Author: Pete Shinners, Rene Dudfield, Marcus von Appen, Bob Pendleton, others...

Author-email: pygame@seul.org
License: LGPL
Location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Was the _view module deprecated at a certain point? My application runs fine when I take out `import pygame._view`, but I would like to be able to build older releases that have `import pygame._view` included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it myself, and there is no module from pygame that is called "_view" or "view".

I've tried `import pygame._view`, `import pygame.view`, `from pygame import _view` and `from pygame import view` in the Python 3.5.3 and 2.7.13 console, with no `_view` module. If you [read the Pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html), you would've found out that there is no `_view` module in the top packages.

If I were you, I would just not have that there IMAO. And if you just `import pygame` or `from pygame import *` you should be fine.

Comment: My old program had this import. I can't remember why I put it there. But this answer was true that I just deleted it then the error was cleared.